# Tikz: control where path meets a node in a path diagram

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes, paths

I'm trying to make a path diagram for my thesis and I'm running into trouble right at the beginning: I want the arrows to end below the y-rectangles (meaning at the lower side of the rectangles). I just started using tikz and I can't find any solution on how to control where the path ends.

This is my code:

```
\documentclass[
12pt,
a4paper,
parskip=never,           % hier ist angegeben, dass kein Einrücken nach den Absätzen gemacht werden soll
captions=tableheading,
nooneline,               % Unterscheidung zwischen ein- und mehrzeiligen Über- bzw. Unterschriften abschalten
numbers=noenddot,
headings=small,
twoside,                 % da gebunden zweiseitig einstellen: innenrand dann größer als äußerer Rand
BCOR=10mm,
listof=flat,
]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture}

\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric,arrows}
\usepackage{caption}

\tikzstyle{manifest} = [rectangle, minimum width = 1cm, minimum height = 1cm, text centered, draw = black]
\tikzstyle{growthparameters} = [circle, minimum width = 2cm, text centered, draw = black]
\tikzstyle{arrow} = [draw, thick, ->, >=stealth]


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance = 4cm]

\node (y1) [manifest] {$Y_{i1}$};
\node (y2) [manifest, right of = y1] {$Y_{i2}$};
\node (y3) [manifest, right of = y2] {$Y_{i3}$};
\node (y4) [manifest, right of = y3] {$Y_{i4}$};
\node (y5) [manifest, right of = y4] {$Y_{i5}$};
\node (y6) [manifest, right of = y5] {$Y_{i6}$};
\node (y7) [manifest, right of = y6] {$Y_{i7}$};
\node (y8) [manifest, right of = y7] {$Y_{i8}$};
\node (y9) [manifest, right of = y8] {$Y_{i9}$};
\node (y10) [manifest, right of = y9] {$Y_{i10}$};
\node (y11) [manifest, right of = y10] {$Y_{i11}$};
\node (y12) [manifest, right of = y11] {$Y_{i12}$};
\node (mu0) [growthparameters, below of = y2, yshift = -3cm] {$\mu_\alpha$};
\node (mu1) [growthparameters, below of = y5, yshift = -3cm] {$\mu_{\beta_1}$};
\node (mu2) [growthparameters, below of = y8, yshift = -3cm] {$\mu_{\beta_2}$};

\draw [arrow] (mu0) -- (y1);
\draw [arrow] (mu0) -- (y2) ;
\draw [arrow] (mu0) -- (y3) ;
\draw [arrow] (mu0) -- (y4) ;
\draw [arrow] (mu0) -- (y5) ;
\draw [arrow] (mu0) -- (y6) ;
\draw [arrow] (mu0) -- (y7) ;
\path [arrow] (mu0) -- (y8) ;
\draw [arrow] (mu0) -- (y9) ;
\draw [arrow] (mu0) -- (y10);
\draw [arrow] (mu0) -- (y11);
\draw [arrow] (mu0) -- (y12);

\draw [arrow] (mu1) -- (y4) ;
\draw [arrow] (mu1) -- (y5) ;
\draw [arrow] (mu1) -- (y6) ;
\draw [arrow] (mu1) -- (y7) ;
\draw [arrow] (mu1) -- (y8) ;
\draw [arrow] (mu1) -- (y9) ;
\draw [arrow] (mu1) -- (y10);
\draw [arrow] (mu1) -- (y11);
\draw [arrow] (mu1) -- (y12);

\draw [arrow] (mu2) -- (y10);
\draw [arrow] (mu2) -- (y11);
\draw [arrow] (mu2) -- (y12);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

This results in:

[image]

Comment: A very quick fix is to replace `(y<i>)` by `(y<i>.south)` in all the arrow paths.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use anchors of nodes for your path ends, such as `nodeName.south`, `nodeName.north`, etc. Check the [manual](https://www.bu.edu/math/files/2013/08/tikzpgfmanual.pdf) Section 17.5 and picture below:
[image: Node's anchors]

For your problem, you can add `.north` in your lower nodes, and `.south` in your upper nodes.

```
\documentclass[
12pt,
a4paper,
parskip=never,           % hier ist angegeben, dass kein Einrücken nach den Absätzen gemacht werden soll
captions=tableheading,
nooneline,               % Unterscheidung zwischen ein- und mehrzeiligen Über- bzw. Unterschriften abschalten
numbers=noenddot,
headings=small,
twoside,                 % da gebunden zweiseitig einstellen: innenrand dann größer als äußerer Rand
BCOR=10mm,
listof=flat,
]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture}

\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric,arrows}
\usepackage{caption}

\tikzstyle{manifest} = [rectangle, minimum width = 1cm, minimum height = 1cm, text centered, draw = black]
\tikzstyle{growthparameters} = [circle, minimum width = 2cm, text centered, draw = black]
\tikzstyle{arrow} = [draw, thick, ->, >=stealth]


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance = 4cm]

\node (y1) [manifest] {$Y_{i1}$};
\node (y2) [manifest, right of = y1] {$Y_{i2}$};
\node (y3) [manifest, right of = y2] {$Y_{i3}$};
\node (y4) [manifest, right of = y3] {$Y_{i4}$};
\node (y5) [manifest, right of = y4] {$Y_{i5}$};
\node (y6) [manifest, right of = y5] {$Y_{i6}$};
\node (y7) [manifest, right of = y6] {$Y_{i7}$};
\node (y8) [manifest, right of = y7] {$Y_{i8}$};
\node (y9) [manifest, right of = y8] {$Y_{i9}$};
\node (y10) [manifest, right of = y9] {$Y_{i10}$};
\node (y11) [manifest, right of = y10] {$Y_{i11}$};
\node (y12) [manifest, right of = y11] {$Y_{i12}$};
\node (mu0) [growthparameters, below of = y2, yshift = -3cm] {$\mu_\alpha$};
\node (mu1) [growthparameters, below of = y5, yshift = -3cm] {$\mu_{\beta_1}$};
\node (mu2) [growthparameters, below of = y8, yshift = -3cm] {$\mu_{\beta_2}$};

\draw [arrow] (mu0.north) -- (y1.south);
\draw [arrow] (mu0.north) -- (y2.south) ;
\draw [arrow] (mu0.north) -- (y3.south) ;
\draw [arrow] (mu0.north) -- (y4.south) ;
\draw [arrow] (mu0.north) -- (y5.south) ;
\draw [arrow] (mu0.north) -- (y6.south) ;
\draw [arrow] (mu0.north) -- (y7.south) ;
\path [arrow] (mu0.north) -- (y8.south) ;
\draw [arrow] (mu0.north) -- (y9.south) ;
\draw [arrow] (mu0.north) -- (y10.south);
\draw [arrow] (mu0.north) -- (y11.south);
\draw [arrow] (mu0.north) -- (y12.south);

\draw [arrow] (mu1.north) -- (y4.south) ;
\draw [arrow] (mu1.north) -- (y5.south) ;
\draw [arrow] (mu1.north) -- (y6.south) ;
\draw [arrow] (mu1.north) -- (y7.south) ;
\draw [arrow] (mu1.north) -- (y8.south) ;
\draw [arrow] (mu1.north) -- (y9.south) ;
\draw [arrow] (mu1.north) -- (y10.south);
\draw [arrow] (mu1.north) -- (y11.south);
\draw [arrow] (mu1.north) -- (y12.south);

\draw [arrow] (mu2.north) -- (y10.south);
\draw [arrow] (mu2.north) -- (y11.south);
\draw [arrow] (mu2.north) -- (y12.south);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

A proposal using conditional to define which position should connect the line according to the node. I changed to the stadalone environment since size of the draw is too broad and I do not know what size it will have, but you can export it to your main document and size it with the graphicx package. Also change the direct lines by lines with corners with rounded edges. I do not know if it can be an alternative or have a better presentation, I think it's users taste.

RESULT:
[image]

MWE:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=15pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric,arrows.meta,positioning}

\tikzstyle{manifest} = []
\tikzstyle{growthparameters} = []
\tikzstyle{arrow} = []

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
        %Environment cfg
        %Environment styles
        manifest/.style={
            rectangle,
            draw,
            minimum width=1cm,
            minimum height=1cm,
            text centered,
        },
        growthparameters/.style={
            circle,
            draw,
            minimum width = 2cm,
            text centered
        },
        arrow/.style={
            draw,
            line width=1pt,
            ->,
            >={Stealth[length=7pt]},
            rounded corners=0.5cm
        }
    ]
        \foreach \n [count=\m from 0]in {1,...,12}{
            \def\NodeDistance{2cm}
            \node(y\n)[manifest] at (\m*\NodeDistance,0){$Y_{i\n}$};
        }

        \node (mu0) [growthparameters, below= 5 of y2] {$\mu_\alpha$};
        \node (mu1) [growthparameters, below= 5 of y5] {$\mu_{\beta_1}$};
        \node (mu2) [growthparameters, below= 5 of y8] {$\mu_{\beta_2}$};

        \foreach \n in {1,...,12}{
            \ifnum\n<4\draw[arrow] (mu0) -- ++(0,5-\n*0.1) -| (y\n);
            \else
            \draw[arrow] (mu0) -- ++(0,5-\n*0.1) -| (y\n.-120);
            \fi
        }
        \foreach \n in {4,...,12}{
            \draw[arrow] (mu1) -- ++(0,4-\n*0.1) -| (y\n);
        }
        \foreach \n in {10,...,12}{
            \draw[arrow] (mu2) -- ++(0,3.5-\n*0.1) -| (y\n.-60);
        }
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a proposal makes sure that the arrows always end at the southern border, but the position depends on where the arrow comes from. BTW, with `\foreach` you can avoid having to repeat things.

```
\documentclass[
12pt,
a4paper,
parskip=never,           % hier ist angegeben, dass kein Einrücken nach den Absätzen gemacht werden soll
captions=tableheading,
nooneline,               % Unterscheidung zwischen ein- und mehrzeiligen Über- bzw. Unterschriften abschalten
numbers=noenddot,
headings=small,
twoside,                 % da gebunden zweiseitig einstellen: innenrand dann größer als äußerer Rand
BCOR=10mm,
listof=flat,
]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture}

\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric,arrows,babel,calc}
\usepackage{caption}

\tikzset{manifest/.style={rectangle, minimum width = 1cm, minimum height = 1cm, text centered, draw = black},
growthparameters/.style={circle, minimum width = 2cm, text centered, draw = black},
arrow/.style={draw, thick, ->, >=stealth}}

\tikzset{my arrow/.style={to path={let \p1=(\tikztostart),\p2=(\tikztotarget),
\n1={-90-0.5*(-90+(180-atan2(\y2-\y1,\x2-\x1)))}
in (\tikztostart) -- (\tikztotarget.\n1) \tikztonodes},-stealth}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance = 4cm]

\node (y1) [manifest] {$Y_{i1}$};
\node (y2) [manifest, right of = y1] {$Y_{i2}$};
\node (y3) [manifest, right of = y2] {$Y_{i3}$};
\node (y4) [manifest, right of = y3] {$Y_{i4}$};
\node (y5) [manifest, right of = y4] {$Y_{i5}$};
\node (y6) [manifest, right of = y5] {$Y_{i6}$};
\node (y7) [manifest, right of = y6] {$Y_{i7}$};
\node (y8) [manifest, right of = y7] {$Y_{i8}$};
\node (y9) [manifest, right of = y8] {$Y_{i9}$};
\node (y10) [manifest, right of = y9] {$Y_{i10}$};
\node (y11) [manifest, right of = y10] {$Y_{i11}$};
\node (y12) [manifest, right of = y11] {$Y_{i12}$};
\node (mu0) [growthparameters, below of = y2, yshift = -3cm] {$\mu_\alpha$};
\node (mu1) [growthparameters, below of = y5, yshift = -3cm] {$\mu_{\beta_1}$};
\node (mu2) [growthparameters, below of = y8, yshift = -3cm] {$\mu_{\beta_2}$};

\foreach \X in {1,...,12} 
{\draw  (mu0) edge[my arrow] (y\X);}

\foreach \X in {4,...,12} 
{\draw  (mu1) edge[my arrow] (y\X);}

\foreach \X in {10,11,12} 
{\draw  (mu2) edge[my arrow] (y\X);}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]